# C++ class inheritance, calling class functions with pointers

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have base class (virtual), with some children, and an array with pointers on base classes. When I create new object and then add its adress to the array, its ok. But when instead of adding adress I use new class(), the PARENT function is called, not the CHILD. Example code:

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual int foo() {return 1;};
};

class child : public base
{
  int foo() {return 2;};
};

//somewhere in code...

vector<base*> arr;

//1. Its ok:
child one;
arr.push_back(&one);
cout<<arr[0].foo(); //Its 2

//2. Its not ok...
arr.push_back(new child())

cout<<arr[1].foo(); //Its 1...
```

Thanx for ay help...

EDIT:

Im sorry, it was compiler fault - Downloaded MinGW and works fine... Sorry for problem...

Comment: Please create a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the error. http://sscce.org

Comment: works fine for me on [ideone](http://ideone.com/uvW9g)

Comment: The code you present should not have that behavior. If that is really the code and you are seeing that effect, check that the compiler is correctly installed, as it is misbehaving., but I doubt it. I am more inclined to think that you are not presenting the real code....

Comment: @Rob its complete, ive just skipped the #include, namespace and main, sorry for that im in a hurry now...

Comment: works fine for me on visual studio 8.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: That can't be the real code (it'd be `->foo`, not `.foo` for a start).

Comment: I am sorry, but you code display 2 and 2...

Comment: wait a moment, i'll update the code with my own code, not just sample, you wouldnt be able to compile, becouse its 12 files, but you may see what's wrong...

Comment: Can't you isolate the problem into a real, working sample?

Comment: "its complete, I just skipped ..."  Then it isn't *complete*, is it? As others have pointed out, if one adds the missing bits, it still won't compile. Please copy-paste a small, complete program. Otherwise, we'll have to resort to mind-reading to determine the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foo is not public in child

```
class child : public base
{   
public:
  int foo() {return 2;};
};
```

also while I am here it should be

```
arr[0]->foo();
```

so

```
child one;
arr.push_back(&one);
arr.push_back(new child());
for(const base* b : arr)//C++11
    std::cout << b->foo() << '\n';
```

result

```
2
2
```

Comment: Well other than the dereferencing issue and a missing ; it builds and executes fine using Apple clang++ 3.0 and Apple llvm-g++ 4.2.1

Comment: @cli_hlt to be honest I aren't entirely sure how the protection level should interact with virtual functions, but I do know I is a lot cleaner (and clearer) to ensure that a overidden functions have the same protection level as the base.

Comment: @111111 Yeah I am absolutely on your side here, I just wanted to state that it indeed compiles and executes nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your provided example should not compile at all as you are declaring a `vector<base*>` and are accessing its elements using  the `.` operator. If that compiles, your compiler is broken, so better delete it and install a decent one.

Other than that, do a

```
arr[0]->foo();
```

and

```
arr[1]->foo();
```

That should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `foo` function must be public. Moreover, since you have a vector of *"pointer to base"*, you must dereference (`*arr[i]`) its elements in order to call `foo` function, otherwise the code is not built.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
    virtual int foo() {return 1;};
};

class child : public base
{
public:   // correction # 0
  int foo() {return 2;};
};

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    vector<base*> arr;

    child one;
    arr.push_back(&one);
    cout << (*arr[0]).foo() << endl;   // correction # 1

    arr.push_back(new child());
    cout << (*arr[1]).foo() << endl;   // correction # 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code using Apple's LLVM compiler and tested it.  Your mileage may vary depending upon the compiler you use.

- 111111 is right in that the method should be public in the child class.  LLVM didn't care and gave 2 as a result in both cases.
- Missing a semi-colon after arr.push_back(new child());
- You should be referencing arr[0]->foo()  (arr[0] is of type base*, a vector of pointers)
- Pushing back a reference of a stack variable is typically a bad idea (just noting even though it probably was done to show the problem)

As I type new answers are being added!

Here's some working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
    virtual int foo() {return 1;};
};

class child : public base
{
    int foo() {return 2;};
};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<base*> arr;

    //1. Its ok:
    child one;
    arr.push_back(&one);
    cout<<arr[0]->foo() << endl; //Its 2

    //2. Its not ok...
    arr.push_back(new child());

    cout<<arr[1]->foo() << endl; //Its 2...
    return 0;
}
```